# How do I use two VPNs at the same time?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am trying to use `Pritunl VPN` which runs over UDP protocol, however for some reason I am only able to use VPNs which use TCP protocol. So what I am trying to achieve is to connect any VPN which uses TCP and then connect to `Pritunl VPN`.

So my data first transfer over TCP from my first VPN and then from inside the first VPN, my data would transfer over `Pritunl VPN` with the UDP protocol.

Is this at all possible? And how can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really out the box solution but what I ended up doing was that I bought an EC2 at aws and ran the VPN from the EC2 instead of running it from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely run into some sort of routing error. The 1st VPN would likely kill the 2nd or vice versa